# Unable to start springboot app - Resource location must not be null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Tried springboot for the first time but I am unable to get it to start.
I used the sample app: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git
I also made modifications to use an embedded jetty instead of tomcat but still no success.

The exception I get is this: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null.

This is on MacOSX.

Edit: I have confirmed this is an environment issue. I can start the app just fine in a linux(fedora) VM but for whatever reason I run into this problem on my Mac. Not sure if anyone else run into this and has any clues on what might be causing this.

Edit 2: So this appears to be an issue with trying to configure ssl by default. I am not sure why this is the case since I haven't specified this anywhere; So my question now is, how do I disable https in spring-boot?

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T09:29:23-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.5/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes!/:0.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:131) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSslKeyStore(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:417) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSsl(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:395) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.customizeSsl(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:332) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:311) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:169) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please paste entire stack trace

Comment: The stack trace shows that your app is still using Tomcat. It also looks like you're trying to configure SSL but that the configuration is incomplete. A complete example that reproduces the problem would make it much easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Agree with @AndyWilkinson on the embedded server is still tomcat than Jetty. I've tried to find the root exception "Resource location must not be null" for the spring-core dependency here - **https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.4.RELEASE/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.java** Line - 131. It seems your app missing (some necessary!?) resources in your classpath. hope you get an idea how to resolve it from there.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson The stack trace is before I even made any of my changes to use jetty. I am running into this problem with the default project as is. Step by step of what I am doing:
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git 
In gs-spring-boot/complete, mvn package & java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
That is all. 
@ satya I figured as much (about resources) but there is no other info on what kind of resources I may be needing. I also went over the ResourceUtils.java but that didn't help shed any light on this.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson
I have confirmed this is an environment issue. I can start the app just fine in a linux VM but for whatever reason I run into this problem on my Mac.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding: 
`server.ssl.enabled=false` 
in my application.properties solved the problem. I assume ssl configuration was expected based on the parent boot starter pom?? Again, not sure why this is working fine in a linux VM. 
Don't have time to dive deeper into this, maybe someone else can shed a bit more light.

Comment: I would guess that your Mac has an environment variable or similar that's trying to configure SSL

Answer (score 11):

I had been disabling and enabling HTTPS (`server.ssl.enabled=true`) but had forgotten to add these back:

```
server.ssl.key-store=file:///Users/...
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
```

Might help some one in the future.

Answer (score 6):

This might help someone:

Any ssl config could cause this, In my case I had following left over configuration:

```
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
```

removing these fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I had `ssl.enabled : true` but other SSL parameters were not set (because of bad indentation in YAML file). This is how it looks in **config/application.yaml** when working good.

```
environments:
  production:
    server:
      port: 9080
      ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: /home/peter/app/ucast.rewara.com/ucast.rewara.com.cert.jks
        key-store-password: drowssapekaf
        key-password: ewerw23121sdsd
        key-alias: ucast.rewara.com
    grails:
      serverURL: "https://ucast.rewara.com:9080"`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could config in file application.properties

```
#SSL:
server.ssl.enabled=false
```

If you want to build local. It will not force you to provide the associated certificates for the SSL (http://)

 Else you build in remote server (https://) -> using ssl -> true.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my application.yml

```
ssl:
    key-store: classpath:xxxx
    key-store-type: yyyy
    key-store-password:
    key-alias: zzzz
```

Changed it to

```
server:
    ssl:
        key-store: classpath:xxxx
        key-store-type: yyyy
        key-store-password:
        key-alias: zzzz
```

and it worked