# Resource location must not be null error to init springboot with different environments

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, https

I have a springBoot project, which is deployed in two different environments (we can tell them env1 and env2) those environments are being created under AWS console. Both environments, we're working as expected, but for some reason `env2` stop to work and now, when I try to run my project under that env I always get the following error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:port', transport: 'socket'
```

I have searched a lot and I found that if I add in my application.properties the following line I'm able to run the project as expected.

```
server.ssl.enabled=false
```

I need to find the root cause about why I have to add that line to my app.properties to be able to run the project in `env2`.
I have tried to do a debug launching the project to see what is the root cause but the first line that I can catch is after the error.

This is the complete stack trace

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52631,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.profiles.active=stg -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -javaagent:/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar -javaagent:/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/user/Documents/test/wtest/repos/wse-wtest-service/build/classes/java/main:/Users/user/Documents/test/wtest/repos/wse-wtest-service/build/resources/main:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web-services/2.0.5.RELEASE/5b023a2fc51b598a6488ae65554af2b40c7a0af8/spring-boot-starter-web-services-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-config-server/2.0.0.RELEASE/6838e58b0362b528160eaa1c23679bf4bac9b8ab/spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.0.5.RELEASE/52daa1f1509bd637a737206e54c06a17aabb9504/spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.0.5.RELEASE/d5153c71f55aa39593fb6295790aad7cd81ef296/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.0.5.RELEASE/5a53ddfd9ebd108f914f390981d992bacabf29d3/spring-boot-starter-security-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.0.5.RELEASE/c99b58e8ada11478aa5d0c3065745b7e887f094e/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.16.20/ac76d9b956045631d1561a09289cbf472e077c01/lombok-1.16.20.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/5.12/a5ed672ed58c367108c94badffe017986389bba9/nimbus-jose-jwt-5.12.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.176/3c90532c7acf52bdf37f475d3900ad1f2d2c3695/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.176.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config/2.0.0.RELEASE/42b4123971eabeefb943d822a568725e9d8045da/spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.highdeal/core_client/sp14/5c82e3ce634e1f8882433c2c17920238c75457b/core_client-sp14.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.highdeal/common_message/sp14/5df565f5bf6336535046fbf3658d1ada7027270e/common_message-sp14.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.highdeal/common_util/sp14/410cded61cf0096c4efbf8de9b39ffe2b5fa7e6a/common_util-sp14.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.highdeal/core_admin/sp14/8c5f88a42b8f3a4694aac58089509c56e0c7839c/core_admin-sp14.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/b0236b252e86419eef20c31a44579d2aee2f0a69/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.oracle/ojdbc5/11.2.0.3/9a36ca0197d24f8ad0d2a47066e129be354ae408/ojdbc5-11.2.0.3.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-security/2.4.4.RELEASE/c2a00fc999d6e36cedef429087029132c5055e03/spring-ws-security-2.4.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j/1.6.19/2d4d36b6a423aa14fd0a57a52ec8f25d3d5dc19a/wss4j-1.6.19.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.0.5.RELEASE/1f53487a373be18d064a5815e9bac9882ef15cdc/spring-boot-starter-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core/3.0.3.RELEASE/9175b57d3335b1815d65ca8183ab0ce4f69904e1/spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-oxm/5.0.9.RELEASE/917a7d5ef27fdd3dc523d191c7505677144d4ec7/spring-oxm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-config-client/2.0.0.RELEASE/7a3f4447664c61ff674c29a9b2ff0dc988dee316/spring-cloud-config-client-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache/4.11.0.201803080745-r/1fa8ea9c093fd288283dc50107d078d4752ba7fc/org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/4.11.0.201803080745-r/4ae44a6157e1bc4c5b373be0c274a8f1d9badd76/org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto/5.0.8.RELEASE/9492d390a7305dd5b509df6d25ac5591b4d206c2/spring-security-crypto-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.5.RELEASE/31bd1111ada2f455eb0f492ed09e39deda18ca99/spring-security-rsa-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/2d998d3d674b172a588e54ab619854d073f555b5/snakeyaml-1.19.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.0.5.RELEASE/d0052ded4733ceb1fb7d927238f22f9a92099227/spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.0.5.RELEASE/eaac8a5d73b45400bc88cd7f6b5c99b5f0d5e9b7/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.12.Final/478003e61b056c1f97840ba3e62ff31cdc89597/hibernate-validator-6.0.12.Final.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.9.RELEASE/c18346caaeb8dc648c4cc01874996fd9fef76664/spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/5.0.9.RELEASE/1ea3aab93340849313fa74ec626ddaf1fff9ed8e/spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.0.5.RELEASE/b29cda343b80e9294646070a5e0d353c3f9f01d1/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.6/50299bc8a34c251d62311bbb1a297f3942a82e42/micrometer-core-1.0.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/5.0.8.RELEASE/87b45329699c294ccd6df2507a1f703eca89e381/spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/5.0.8.RELEASE/83a070861ad63c0dd5660d4529b9c37a3c9e3c50/spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.0.9.RELEASE/98003b099697fe46b6bdf18c7e3f66d7a1381060/spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.0.5.RELEASE/6bc1e8bcc849772d48cae1e8278cd2b471361698/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.0.5.RELEASE/9a5370acc7c5e17f4a00578211fbbd212b9a8329/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.0.10.RELEASE/a6e644c363d050c6c90f078f4f0ac66892f60d54/spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/d81aff979d603edd90dcd8db2abc1f4ce6479e3e/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.17.Final/f2dc36470e7a2ffcf6106bb1625ecf5b54bb5f65/hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/5.0.9.RELEASE/dfb2da4c573391d8e8a482f08bdf4d38398e2bb0/spring-aspects-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.stephenc.jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0-1/ef31541dd28ae2cefdd17c7ebf352d93e9058c63/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.minidev/json-smart/2.3/7396407491352ce4fa30de92efb158adb76b5b/json-smart-2.3.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.11.336/94eabca535897b3f71de7df4536e61eec159ad0/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.336.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.336/843b0108a4a0d437182c3b155cda229d78c66c47/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.336.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/jmespath-java/1.11.336/2ffaab56cec055a6e63aeb569d69fead74261dc5/jmespath-java-1.11.336.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config/2.0.0.RELEASE/6758e8c95e8783b95291225ea449d1497e0e35d2/spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/5.0.8.RELEASE/32a39026edcb6b7cd4567df2c75bd561d876f515/spring-security-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.ws/spring-xml/3.0.3.RELEASE/22933f459b5d6a7a3c2c71578df004846571b26e/spring-xml-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-dom/2.1.11/7bea9932dd85cbe87c729986fe68b04c50e951fa/wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.1.11.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.5/74c1ec0a88bf20a14edb1b30a92b4c33cc6ea6b0/ehcache-2.10.5.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/4bfc12adfe4842bf07b657f0369c4cb522955686/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.0.9.RELEASE/d3a13fc3c56bdddd8144a686ed64f0cdb3ad7305/spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.0.9.RELEASE/65f56fdab1bb90ad059e314d2f2f4cf76f9bdbde/spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.9.RELEASE/9f9a828936d81afd49a603bda9cc1aed863a0d85/spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml/2.5.1-1/9736dcbe852dda3ce263a9c6e33579cd5af203e5/opensaml-2.5.1-1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.santuario/xmlsec/2.0.9/c53ce109d6d283a2c01d8e4f8282b1d01d615470/xmlsec-2.0.9.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.0.5.RELEASE/e5588642799e0c0c04638e255c3d3f31ba400ff4/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.0.5.RELEASE/19a4624cbd89a318d10c79f289c6c816043850fb/spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.0.5.RELEASE/c353e0b9591d0765c687ff0a678478cbebfd5c23/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/2852e6e05fbb95076fc091f6d1780f1f8fe35e0f/commons-io-2.5.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context/2.0.0.RELEASE/3f0d28344c0dc74eb8594f3f3dd6f82c687be198/spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons/2.0.0.RELEASE/54ba9a1ace0a8c8e0dd0cdf30e59def4700ab854/spring-cloud-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/cfa4f316351a91bfd95cb0644c6a2c95f52db1fc/jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/1afe5621985efe90a92d0fbc9be86271efbe796f/httpclient-4.5.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/acc54d9b28bdffe4bbde89ed2e4a1e86b5285e2b/httpcore-4.4.10.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.54/da3584329a263616e277e15462b387addd1b208d/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jcraft/jzlib/1.1.1/a1551373315ffc2f96130a0e5704f74e151777ba/jzlib-1.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.googlecode.javaewah/JavaEWAH/1.1.6/94ad16d728b374d65bd897625f3fbb3da223a2b6/JavaEWAH-1.1.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/4648af70268b6fdb24674fb1fd7c1fcc73db1231/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.6/456895fc91bf7180b216fead220373e6278230c9/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.6/ea54f6193d224e5e5732bbd4262327eb465397c2/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.6/129acd77a4b6ee30d62d3a0899b1344c8ec2bff8/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.34/5f86906367c2540b21e6aeecc277d2ce9ec939b0/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.34/a038040d68a90397f95dd1e11b979fe364a5000f/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.34/be71a9a5bdd001db7cf97c47429eec0bdd3b7b88/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.34.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/3d5f48f10bbe4eb7bd862f10c0583be2e0053c6/classmate-1.3.4.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.0.9.RELEASE/2501e55acb6c2e84667cda3f845d1d00a0dc4e05/spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.0.9.RELEASE/1f9db5ff3a758102c0434cc3457aa47c50c39a4a/spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.0.5.RELEASE/7daa40cc91678aee37009b595c4cee4b05de3d68/spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.10/9e1ac84eed220281841b75e72fb9de5a297fbf04/HdrHistogram-2.1.10.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/769c0b82cb2421c8256300e907298a9410a2a3d3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.13/ad94df2a28d658a40dc27bbaff6a1ce5fbf04e9b/aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.7.9/a83113d2c091d0d0f853dad3217bd7df3beb6ae3/HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.0.9.RELEASE/2f38726ef2f5ecb72af7e915dac43177b01a8f53/spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/2.0.10.RELEASE/64d4e58a2b16b9446d51a2650058d821a5bce98d/spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.0.9.RELEASE/bb9265effd7c903f4cc1c98d16b4188b7827a1cc/spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/71e1cff3fcb20d3b3af4f3363c3ddb24d33c6879/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.2.Final/52afb5762c704a6b586e27742470c08f91877fc1/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.22.0-GA/3e83394258ae2089be7219b971ec21a8288528ad/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/bfc4d6257dbff7a33a357f0de116be6ff951d849/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.minidev/accessors-smart/1.2/c592b500269bfde36096641b01238a8350f8aa31/accessors-smart-1.2.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/1.11.336/acb59583e19fb1daaafaa0cc8d94daaf6ee56d85/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.336.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/software.amazon.ion/ion-java/1.0.2/ee9dacea7726e495f8352b81c12c23834ffbc564/ion-java-1.0.2.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor/2.9.6/2bf7323658396d1fd4d75fc1fc5126acbfc216ad/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.9.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9/f7b520c458572890807d143670c9b24f4de90897/joda-time-2.9.9.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssm/1.11.336/1dab90e2c512b2b40cca61ad1d568017a803ad8/aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.336.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-common/2.1.11/779d4a47fe58c407a7c620bfe50c3c84f1e6b566/wss4j-ws-security-common-2.1.11.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.9.RELEASE/bc3b5aaae53f0bc03647e53ecbd98a05b47a4e90/spring-jcl-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-1.7.25.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.6/4e393793c37c77e042ccc7be5a914ae39251b365/jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/a153c6f9744a3e9dd6feab5e210e1c9861362ec7/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/5.0.4/da08b8cce7bbf903602a25a3a163ae252435795/asm-5.0.4.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-xacml-saml-impl/3.1.1/fb9dfb4460959ce2ca2aa1d781df2465a2372d83/opensaml-xacml-saml-impl-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-saml-impl/3.1.1/2d2ad57af6123af47df93b38f449b5cb19e374f2/opensaml-saml-impl-1.2.3.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.10.0/fec5797a55b786184a537abd39c3fa1449d752d6/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-xacml-saml-api/3.1.1/42b3791a481f66cf449d2c9510c884e93dcb7f2c/opensaml-xacml-saml-api-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.shibboleth.utilities/java-support/7.1.1/7380a42d4ef28f98f73657b0d0cbe59a8eba605b/java-support-7.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-xmlsec-impl/3.1.1/c62cddd3a5bcc04243aa9b978a4848be882af473/opensaml-xmlsec-impl-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-saml-api/3.1.1/83f423f7d055037737197c2c1cdb8ae3b8c4875/opensaml-saml-api-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-security-impl/3.1.1/110e40459c769148495fddbf1f4b9dd3f5afeafb/opensaml-security-impl-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-profile-api/3.1.1/2cca31d4b61ecd0237978ae4c08b9872aa2590f8/opensaml-profile-api-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-xacml-api/3.1.1/b0f10086fb128ed01fdd6a507216d9e1b9add489/opensaml-xacml-api-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/18.0/cce0823396aa693798f8882e64213b1772032b09/guava-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-security-api/3.1.1/9e5e0625a4eaa52d40c3ddd1025b1cfdca87facf/opensaml-security-api-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opensaml/opensaml-core/3.1.1/b72f6b92bdff0fe6b590a46f7a8958c84c654729/opensaml-core-3.1.1.jar:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.cryptacular/cryptacular/1.0/a7dd8234498f8425c25e983b4d3451d7accb0b5b/cryptacular-1.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar com.test.dpe.spg.wtest.controller.Application
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52631', transport: 'socket'
2022-06-10 15:58:07.590  INFO 64520 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6ae5aa72: startup date [Fri Jun 10 15:58:07 COT 2022]; root of context hierarchy
2022-06-10 15:58:09.044  INFO 64520 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4218ca6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

2022-06-10 15:58:18.541  INFO 64520 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='aws-param-store', propertySources=[AwsParamStorePropertySource {name='/config/null_stg/'}, AwsParamStorePropertySource {name='/config/null/'}, AwsParamStorePropertySource {name='/config/application_stg/'}, AwsParamStorePropertySource {name='/config/application/'}]}
2022-06-10 15:58:18.897  INFO 64520 --- [           main] c.a.d.spg.wtest.controller.Application  : The following profiles are active: stg
2022-06-10 15:58:19.066  INFO 64520 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@76a82f33: startup date [Fri Jun 10 15:58:19 COT 2022]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6ae5aa72
2022-06-10 15:58:31.822  INFO 64520 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=refresh; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]
2022-06-10 15:58:36.065  INFO 64520 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=25fc7a1d-e2a8-396f-9bd7-ab6c5e72cb99
2022-06-10 15:58:37.470  INFO 64520 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2c9f4ea8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-06-10 15:58:37.646  INFO 64520 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2022-06-10 15:58:38.464  INFO 64520 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$880789a9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-06-10 15:58:38.879  INFO 64520 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4218ca6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-06-10 15:58:42.506  WARN 64520 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52631', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: Hello @tgdavies that is the full stack trace

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585031/unable-to-start-springboot-app-resource-location-must-not-be-null